# ASP.NET MVC 5 Common actions for more controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have some controllers (and will be more) which share some actions like those:

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Supplier s = db.Suppliers.Find(id);
    s.Deleted = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public ActionResult RestoreConfirmed(int id)
{
    Supplier s = db.Suppliers.Find(id);
    s.Deleted = false;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Those action are part of `SuppliersController`. What this does is that when I delete or restore an object, it marks the object in the database as true for deleted field (and false when it is restored).

The same behavior is shared by many other controllers like `CurrenciesController`, `ProductsController`, etc...

In the code I showed you should see that my database entity is clearly specified (`Supplier`) and also the repository (`Suppliers`).

I want to find a way to this in a generic way. I want to create a custom controller and all other controllers that shares the same behavior will extended it. In this case `ProductsController` will extend my `DeleteRestoreController`.

How can I do this in a "generic" way?

`db` is a `DbContext`

```
public partial class LE: DbContext
{
public LE()
    : base("name=LE")
{
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
}

public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<CategoryText> CategoryTexts { get; set; }
...
}
```

`Categories` also share the same behavior.

Comment: What is `db`?  Is that a Repository object, or a DataContext?  If it's a DataContext, your code is already as optimized as it can be.  If you are using a Repository object behind the controllers, just refactor the first three lines of code into a Repository method, and call that.

Comment: How many instances of this are we talking about?  I don't think it's worth the trouble unless you have 20 or more, and maybe not even then.

Comment: Right now I don't have twenty but I expect a lot of them. Also it's redundant code which can be reduced.

Comment: You reduce it like you reduce any other code duplication, by refactoring the code into a method, and calling the new method instead of the original code.

Comment: I know that but the thing is I don't want to write them. It's the same behavior for all of the controllers, the only thing that differs is the entity type. That's all.

Comment: So it's not just a Supplier then?  If you push it back into a Repository method you're just going to wind up with a big `case` statement containing all of the entities, unless you have a [generic repository](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/572761/Generic-repository-pattern-using-EF-with-Dependenc).  So all you're doing is pushing the complexity somewhere else (although you *are* making your model fatter and your controller thinner).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.

Comment: Nothing to be afraid of.  That's why they invented Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V.  The DB object requires these lines of code; embrace the redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

To go one step further

```
public abstract class DeleteRestoreController<T> : Controller
{

public virtual Action DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    var dbset = db.Set<T>();

    var s = dbset.Find(id);
    s.Deleted = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
}
```

then when defining your controller add the entity type

```
public class ProductsController : DeleteRestoreController<Supplier>
{
////blah
}
```

Comment: You could also add a layer of abstraction like a repository pattern. I've got a UnitOfWork class that has a method public IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : BaseEntity that I can call and gives me a generic repository for what ever entity I give it. My UnitOfWork also has properties for a couple of specific repositories that do things other than that of the generic repo.

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for or something similar. Thank you!

Comment: Also the second idea seems better than your posted solution but some more could would be useful for understanding.

Comment: But ther are also two problem. I need a reference for <T> when setting the dbset and the Deleted property does not exist in this context. Here I don't know what to do

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your `DeleteRestoreController` as an abstract class.

```
public abstract class DeleteRestoreController : Controller
{
    private IRepository : Repository;
    public DeleteRestoreController() { ... }
    public DeleteRestoreController(IRepository Repository) { ... }

    public virtual Action DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Supplier s = db.Suppliers.Find(id);
        s.Deleted = true;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

If you need to differ from that behaviour in your `ProductsController` you can simply override that method.

```
public class ProductsController : DeleteRestoreController
{
    public override void DeleteConfirmed()
    {
        //override the logic
    }
}
```

You could always go one step further and implement a generic repository as well, but I've never gone beyond 6-8 controllers in my applications and didn't create one once.

*EDIT* I've just read in the comments, that the entities would change from `Suppliers` in the controllers, so implementing a base controller wouldn't make much sense, if you do not implement a generic interface as well. Robert Harvey has made a great point in stating the complexity has to go *somewhere*.

Comment: I think Robert Harvey is right and in my case the generic repository may save me. Now I have 10 controllers and I'm expecting for at least 10 more. I have so many because I'm managing almost each entity independently and when it's the case, I associate them.